# ChromeDriver binary not found

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome

trying to run a program that requires ChromeDrivers. Im on Chrome 98 and MacOS. I get the error "ChromeDriver binary not found when running this python program. The program also uses selenium.

Comment: Selenium is well-known for being difficult to install. Suggestion: try Playwright. It's from the team that built a previous Selenium competitor called Puppeteer. It's much easier to install, both locally and in production, and is very capable. Disclaimer: I don't work for Playwright or its associated companies.

Comment: Im not experienced enough to replace Selenium with Playwright. Any ideas how I can specify the location of the ChromeDrivers?